# Clarification needed for what send_data disposition: "inline" does

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am migrating some codebase from an old rails app into a new one and one of the controller methods has this in it.

```
send_data(render_compare_chart(@projects, start_date, end_date),
          :disposition => 'inline', :type => 'image/png' )
```

I looked up the definition of what send_data does and I get it except for this part for the disposition option.

> :disposition    Suggests to the browser that the file should be displayed inline

What exactly does that mean in the context of the code above? Am I supposed to see an image file rendered on the browser or not? Currently I don't see anything that remotely looks like what I'm supposed to be seeing. I don't know what I'm looking for here?

Inside the render_compare_chart method there is some imagemagick stuff going on so I'm wondering if I should be seeing something or not. Can someone clarify what this inline option means? Thanks.

Comment: The documentation seems pretty clear: "disposition - specifies whether the file will be shown inline or downloaded. Valid values are ‘inline’ and ‘attachment’ (default)." Seems to me that you should expect to the see the image on your page. Have you tried taking image magick out of the picture (pun intended) and using a regular image file?

Comment: Haven't tried that but will be doing that. Thanks Sunil.